# How do I create a builder that takes a type that implements AsRef for a slice of `&str`?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am calling a function that takes a `&[&str]`. As it is more convenient to write `["aa", "bb"]`, instead of `&["aa", "bb"]`, I decided to add `AsRef`:

```
struct Builder<'a> {
    s: Option<&'a [&'a str]>,
}

impl<'a> Builder<'a> {
    fn new() -> Builder<'a> {
        Builder { s: None }
    }

    fn abc<S>(&mut self, s: S) -> &mut Self
        where S: AsRef<[&'a str]> + 'a
    {
        self.s = Some(s.as_ref());
        self
    }

    fn build(&self) -> u32 {
        0
    }
}

fn main() {
    Builder::new().abc([]).build();
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=45b3e93d119d36b6cf46b1205cb2a4df&version=stable&backtrace=0))

But there is a problem with lifetime:

```
error: `s` does not live long enough
        self.s = Some(s.as_ref());
                      ^
note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 12:4...
    {
        self.s = Some(s.as_ref());
        self
    }
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the scope of parameters for function at 12:4
    {
        self.s = Some(s.as_ref());
        self
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code tries to transfer ownership of the array to the function `abc([])`, take a reference to the array (`s.as_ref()`), then it **throws away the array**, which would leave a pointer to undefined memory. Rust does not allow you to do that.

> I did it: `self.s = Some(unsafe { std::mem::transmute(s.as_ref()) });`

This is a **very bad idea**. As mentioned above, you now have a reference to an array that no longer exists. That memory is allowed to have *anything* placed there in the future, and accessing the pointer will, in the **best** case, cause your program to crash, but could also continue executing but with nonsense data.

Only use `unsafe` code when you understand all the consequences.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to make `Builder` be generic over `S` and be the owner of parameter `s`:

```
struct Builder<S> {
    s: Option<S>,
}

impl<'a> Builder<[&'a str; 0]> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Builder { s: None }
    }
}

impl<'a, S: AsRef<[&'a str]>> Builder<S> {
    fn abc<T: AsRef<[&'a str]>>(self, s: T) -> Builder<T> {
        Builder {
            // copy other fields, x: self.x, ...
            // and replace s
            s: Some(s)
        }
    }

    fn print_s(&self) {
        // example of using s
        if let Some(ref s) = self.s {
            println!("{:?}", s.as_ref()); // S::as_ref
        } else {
            println!("None");
        }
    }
}
```

Now `abc` can be called with different parameter types:

```
fn main() {
    Builder::new().print_s();
    Builder::new().abc([]).print_s();
    Builder::new().abc(["a", "b"]).print_s();
    Builder::new().abc(&["a", "b", "c"]).print_s();
    Builder::new().abc(vec!["a"]).print_s();
}
```

Comment: How to impl `AsRef` for `str`? `impl<'a, S: AsRef<[AsRef<str>]>> Builder<S> {` don't work.

Comment: I considered suggesting something like this, but since `s` is wrapped in an `Option` it seems like the builder should be able to be called without `abc`. Try that, and you'll see the type cannot be inferred. You could make a default value of `S` or start with an empty array or something. If you *always* need to call `abc`, then it should be provided as part of the builder's constructor and all of this is easier.

Comment: @Lupe Can you clarify what you want with an example?

Comment: Would suggest a `match` and `Some(ref s)`.  Also think OP wants to pass a `Vec<String>`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the observation. I updated the answer. One limitation is that the fields of `Builder` must be copied one by one. There was a thread in users.rust-lang.org (I think) about the impossibility of doing `A{ x = 2, ..a }` if `a: A` and `x` with different generic type, but I didn't find it now.

Comment: @malbarbo I want to call the function like this: `abc([String::from("123"), "321"])`. Does this mean that the implement `AsRef` to `str` will have to re-create the array of references? Or it is possible to do it at compile time?

Comment: Arrays in Rust are homogeneous, you cannot have an array with  `String`s and `&str`s. What you want cannot be done at compile time, not with arrays.

Comment: @malbarbo `String::as_ref()` == `&str`. That is, the array will contain only `&str`.

Comment: @Lupe You cannot write `[String::from("123"), "321"]` anywhere in the code, it will not compile. If you have to mix `String`'s with `&str`'s in an array you have three options: 1) get `&str` from the `String` (`[&s, "321"]`). 2) create a `String` from the `&str` (`[s, "321".to_string()]`). 3) create a `Cow<str>` for each `String` and `&str` (`[Cow::Owned(s), Cow::Borrowed("321")]`).